# Finding totals in group inside a group

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum

I have this table:

```
Id Quantity Type   Period
1A   3       sweet  Q1
2A   2       sweet  Q1
3A   2       salad  Q1
4A   1       sweet  Q2
5A   3       salad  Q2
6A   1       salad  Q2
```

For each period, I need to find the Quantity of sweets (In this case 5 sweets for Q1 and 1 for Q2) and the number of salads per period (2 for Q1) and 4 for Q2.
I tried 'group by' but this time I can identify a group within a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to group by in a group by, just group by both fields:

```
SELECT type, period, sum(qty) as qty FROM table GROUP BY type, period;
```